# Google Maps API V3 API Key not load

Tags: javascript, api, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

i Have a problem with my Javascript and the API KEY. I only want that this code show the map in the browser but it still can't find an API KEY.

I used the google map a few times before but I haven't these problems.

I hope you can help me!

Here is my Code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head >

    <title>maps</title>
    <style type="text/css">
        body {
            height: 100%;
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>



<!-- Load the Google API: -->

 <script src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js"></script>

<script>
var map = {};    
var mapCenter = new google.maps.LatLng(51.0, 1.5); 
var trackList = [];  
var trackSymbolSize = 1.0; 

var MAX_NUMBER_OF_TRACKS = 100000;
var EXCEPTION_AT_LOGICAL_ERROR = true;
var CONSOLE_LOG = true;

function initMap() {
    var mapProp = {
        center: mapCenter,
        zoom: 8,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    };


    document.getElementById("googleMap").style.height = innerHeight + 'px';
    document.getElementById("googleMap").style.width = innerWidth + 'px';

    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("googleMap"), mapProp);
}

function browserResize() {
    document.getElementById("googleMap").style.height = innerHeight + 'px';
    document.getElementById("googleMap").style.width = innerWidth + 'px';

    google.maps.event.trigger(map, 'resize');
}

</script>

<script>

    google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initMap);

</script>

<div id="googleMap"></div>

 <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyDuZVG0Z9Ei7ubm5bkAfPsYUI-Wm8C_c-0&callback=initMap" async defer></script>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: remove upper `<script src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js"></script>` as it already included below with keys

Comment: it seems to me that you have included the map api javascript twice, one is without key (at the top) and maybe the second time it doesnt reload it again?

Comment: do what @Deep3015 says.... DO IT!!!

Comment: Yes I' ve done this but then it also show nothing .

Comment: the error in console is : Uncaught ReferenceError: google is not defined
    at mapkarte.html:71

Comment: maybe this `var mapCenter = new google.maps.LatLng(51.0, 1.5); ` runs before the script has a chance to load. move this line and `google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initMap);` this one to initMap function.. your init map function will automatically be called so you dont even need `google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initMap);` this btw

Comment: yes thanks with the code below it works fine :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try like this.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>

  <title>maps</title>
  <style type="text/css">
    body {
      height: 100%;
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0
    }
  </style>
  <!-- Load the Google API: -->

  <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyDuZVG0Z9Ei7ubm5bkAfPsYUI-Wm8C_c-0&callback=initMap" async defer></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="googleMap"></div>
  <script>
    var map = {};
    var mapCenter
    var trackList = [];
    var trackSymbolSize = 1.0;

    var MAX_NUMBER_OF_TRACKS = 100000;
    var EXCEPTION_AT_LOGICAL_ERROR = true;
    var CONSOLE_LOG = true;

    function initMap() {
      mapCenter = new google.maps.LatLng(51.0, 1.5);
      var mapProp = {
        center: mapCenter,
        zoom: 8,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
      };


      document.getElementById("googleMap").style.height = innerHeight + 'px';
      document.getElementById("googleMap").style.width = innerWidth + 'px';

      map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("googleMap"), mapProp);
    }

    function browserResize() {
      document.getElementById("googleMap").style.height = innerHeight + 'px';
      document.getElementById("googleMap").style.width = innerWidth + 'px';

      google.maps.event.trigger(map, 'resize');
    }
  </script>


</body>

</html>
```